# Confusion over String.Remove

Tags: c#, .net, string

I am having a little trouble understanding why String.Remove is not working in a certain scenario of mine. I have a method (just for some practice) that removes a character within a string based on a given position and works as follows:

```
public static string RemoveCharacter(string word, int pos_to_del)
        {
            int string_length = word.Length;

            if (Enumerable.Range(0, string_length - 1).Contains(pos_to_del))
            {
                word = word.Remove(pos_to_del, pos_to_del);
            }
            return word;
        }
```

If pos_to_del > 0 it will work (ex. word = hello and pos_to_del = 1, result = hllo). However, if the user wants the position to be the first character (0) this will not work. I don't know if I've been coding for too long straight and am making a simple mistake or if there is something about any of this that I actually am misunderstanding.

Comment: FYI `if(pos_to_del < word.Length && pos_to_del >= 0)` would make a lot more sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, this line is no good:

```
if (Enumerable.Range(0, string_length - 1).Contains(pos_to_del))
```

This line isn't the cause of your issue, but it is *an* issue. If your string is very long, you are generating a sequence of numbers as long as that string.  This can be very inefficient, and it isn't necessary.  You can just use a simple comparison:

```
if (pos_to_del >= 0 && pos_to_del < word.Length)
```

Is much better.  You aren't generating a sequence; its performance will be consistent, regardless of the string's length.

Secondly, the second parameter to `string.Remove(int,int)` is the *number of characters* to remove.  This is the cause of your issue: your code currently says to remove zero characters from the first position in the string.  To fix it, just supply 1:

```
word = word.Remove(pos_to_del, 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.remove?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Remove_System_Int32_System_Int32_) second parameter is `The number of characters to delete.` .You need instead:

```
word = word.Remove(pos_to_del, 1);
```